# Centroid-Tracking, How sorting is done properly?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, tracking, opencv

I understand the idea of centroid tracking, but I cannot understand some parts of the code (all available codes nearly takes the one on the topic pyimagesearch). As far as I understand, we need to match the centroids we got with centroids we already have. I understand that there is "kind of sorting" operation need to be done:

for every centroid, find the minimum distance with all new centroids (so we consider the one with the minimum distance as a match)

However, I cannot relate what I understand with the code (specifically the argsort and argmin lines).

Here is the code part which covers this area ([full code](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/23/simple-object-tracking-with-opencv/)).

```
# grab the set of object IDs and corresponding centroids
objectIDs = list(self.objects.keys())
objectCentroids = list(self.objects.values())

""" compute the distance between each pair of object centroids and input centroids, respectively -- our goal will be to 
match an input centroid to an existing object centroid """
D = dist.cdist(np.array(objectCentroids), inputCentroids)

# Next 2 (code) lines are what confuse me:
""" in order to perform this matching we must (1) find the smallest value in each row and then (2) sort the row indexes
based on their minimum values so that the row with the smallest value as at the *front* of the index list """
rows = D.min(axis=1).argsort()

""" next, we perform a similar process on the columns by finding the smallest value in each column and then sorting using
the previously computed row index list """
cols = D.argmin(axis=1)[rows]

""" in order to determine if we need to update, register, or deregister an object we need to keep track of which of the
rows and column indexes we have already examined """
usedRows = set()
usedCols = set()

# loop over the combination of the (row, column) index tuples
for (row, col) in zip(rows, cols):
    # if we have already examined either the row or column value before, ignore its val
    if row in usedRows or col in usedCols:
        continue

    # otherwise, grab the object ID for the current row, set its new centroid, and reset the disappeared counter
    objectID = objectIDs[row]
    self.objects[objectID] = inputCentroids[col]
    self.disappeared[objectID] = 0

    # indicate that we have examined each of the row and column indexes, respectively
    usedRows.add(row)
    usedCols.add(col)
```

What do these lines do in the process?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m assuming the argmin and argsort aren’t defined locally. If they are then show the definitions. Assuming they’re not, a quick search for _python argsort_ leads to a numpy function https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html which appears to give a detailed explanation with examples. I fully expect that searching for _python argmin_ will find a similar numpy page.

Comment: all of them are the numpy ones, I understand them, but cannot relate them with the algorithm itself

Comment: D is the distance matrix such that D,ij = dist(object_Centroids_i,inputCentroid_j). D.min(axis=1) computes the minimum by row. So for every object_centroid, we now have the distances to the closest input. .argsort() sorts the object_centroids by the distance to the closest input and returns the ordering 'rows'. Afterwards we will process them in this order. The second line is quite simple. D.argmin(axis=1) returns the closest input for every object_centroid. Then they're rearanged in the same order by using rows as an index.

Comment: @kubatucka I didn't get the idea of sorting object centroids by distance. why do we need this? why not just getting the min distance for each centroid?

Comment: Because if 2 objects are closest to the same input_centroid, you match the on closest one. For example with 2 objects and 2 inputs D=[[2,5,1,6]. The sorted output will be {(1,0),(0,0)] .We cant match both objects with first input so we'll match the second object with the first input and the second object will be ignored in the for loop.